# Passing Array of Components to Layout using PlainRoute

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I want to pass an array of Components `[AccountSettings, PlanSettings]` to my `SettingsLayout`.

How can I do this using `react-router`'s PlainRoute?

```
export default {
  path: 'settings',
  component: SettingsLayout,
  childRoutes: [
    {
      path: 'account',
      component: [AccountSettings, PlanSettings]
    },
    {
      path: 'notifications',
      component: NotificationSettings
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `components` https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#components-1

and pass an object instead:

```
components: {AccountSettings, PlanSettings}
```

You might even be able to do:

```
components: { components: [ AccountSettings, PlanSettings ] }
```

but I haven't tried that.. doesn't seem super useful even if you could.

Comment: Not working for me.  Do I need to do anything special besides `{this.props.children}` in `SettingsLayout.js`?

Comment: Yes it says in the docs there, use `this.props.AccountSettings` and `this.props.PlanSettings`

Comment: I see. What if I don't want to hardcode their names in SettingsLayout, and I don't have a need for `{main: AccountSettings, sub: PlanSettings}`?  All I want to do is to iterate over however many children were passed down.

Comment: What about creating one component that houses the components you need and pass that to your router component?

Comment: Right, that's my backup.  But if i can pass props down then there should be a way to pass an array of components, no?

Comment: "doesn't seem super useful even if you could." your right for v2/v3.   The new v4 has the right api (just another react component) to make for a concise SFC && eliminate the need for PlainRoutes.  Miss/Match take the place of PlainRoutes 1-to-1, making for an easy upgrade.